# Use Raycast on canvas child gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using this joystick and Mirror for networking

https://github.com/herbou/Unity_EasyJoystick

What I wanted is to detect the gameobject Joystick which is the child of Canvass using Raycast

[image]

I've tried this script

```
public class ShootBullet : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject bulletPrefab;
    private GameObject bullet;

    // Set via the Inspector in Units/second
    [SerializeField] private float _moveSpeed = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private Camera _camera;
    Vector3 touch_Pos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && this.isLocalPlayer)
        {
            Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect ui element use:

`UI.GraphicRaycaster`

more information here
https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html

Comment: Can I use Input.GetTouch(0).position in here?

Comment: I guess you can but not sure about that. but you can use `RaycastResult.screenPosition` if you want to know the position.